# Generating Functions Combinatorial argument

Tags: generating-functions, integer-partitions, combinatorial-proofs

Show that any number of partitions of  $r+k$  into  $k$  parts is equal to the number of partitions of
$$r+\binom{k+1}{2}$$ into $k$ distinct parts for $r \geq k$.

I would like to see a proof for this, my try was incorrect and gives no result.
Does it work for $k \geq r$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Is the discription ok now?

Comment: What was your try? Notice that $\binom{k+1}{2}=k+(k-1)+\cdots +2+1.$

Comment: Latexing, sorry it will take time.

Comment: Realized that the first line of the proof (assumtion) is incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: The [Ferrers diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Ferrers_diagram) of any partition of $r+\binom{k+1}2=r+\sum_{i=1}^ki$ into $k$ distinct parts must have at least $1$ dot in the bottom row, at least $2$ dots, in the next row up, and so on, all the way up to at least $k$ dots in the top row. What do you get if leave the bottom row alone, remove $1$ dot from the next row up, remove $2$ dots from the row above that, and so on, finally removing $k-1$ dots from the top row?